# Type 3 compensator with opamp compare calculation/simu and measured difference

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, simulation, flyback, matlab

I'm designing a type 3 compensator with an opamp for a flyback which is operating in a constant voltage mode.

Therefore I measured the plant and started to design a suitable type 3 compensator to fullfill my phase reserve and gain margin targets. I started first with a analytical calculation to get the correct transfer function of the type 3 (a lot of papers are full of faulty formulas what I noticed, thats why..)

The caclulation were done in matlab

[image: Transfer function type 3]

After comparing it with the simulation (Ltspice) I measured the gain and phase curve compensator with calculated values directly in the circuit with my Bode100 as suggested in the papers from omicron. What I noticed that the gain curve completetly differs from the calculated/simulated one. Only the phase curve fits more the ideal one.

First I tried different injection levels for the disturbance signal. The disturbance signal is injected trough a 10 Ohm resistor which is placed between Vout and the upper parts of R1, R3. And the output signal is measured directly at the output of the opamp and the input signal between Vout and upper pin of R1, R2. Even the closed loop voltage gain bandwidth should be in the MHz region far away because the gain of this compensator design should be < 1? Or am I wrong? what else could be lead to this difference in gain curves?

R3 = 1k, C2=1nF, R1=47k, C3 = 0pF, C1 = 47nF, R2 = 5.6k
Opamp used LM2904B

[image: Type3 compensator]
[image]

I have no clue whats wrong here, is the calculation incorrect or do someone has an idea what can be wrong here? Or what could I check here?

Comment: Calling Verbal Kint!

Comment: It is very likely the op-amp own characteristics affect the response on your board and this is normal. Formulas are derived considering a perfect op-amp with infinite open-loop gain and GBW. Have a look at my [APEC 2015](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202015.pdf) seminar but you can also read my two-part article on the subject [here](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/1701/articles/H2PToday1701_design_ONSemi.pdf?NOREDIR=1) available from [How2Power](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/index.php).

Comment: It might be exactly as Chris (@VerbalKint) says, but another place to look is your component values.  If you're using ceramic caps with class II dielectrics, DC bias, AC excitation, tolerance and aging can all make a very big difference in the effective capacitance value.